# How wrap ul li - s elements

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
<ul class="category-module souvenir"> 
    <li></li>
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
</ul>
```

and I need to wrap `<li>` starting from number 3 into `<div>`
I tried the following:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("souvenir")[1];
    var array = ul.children;
    array[0].slice(4).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" ); 
});
```

**Updated: more detailed description**

I wish to hide all elements but the first three elements. How can this be achieved with jquery?

Comment: `<li>` isn't a valid child of `<div>`. Provide sample of your  expected results. Also show the code you have tried using

Comment: ... and provide what you tried so far.

Comment: "*`The HTML <li> element (or HTML List Item Element) is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (<ol>), an unordered list (<ul>), or a menu (<menu>)`*"[MDN- li element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

Comment: @charlietfl I nnedd to hide and show the part of the li  elements by clicking   a button, how can I do that ?

Comment: based on what conditions? Need better defintiion of problem

Comment: @charlietfl no condition, there is a 12 li element in the block need a button to show and hide 9 of them

Comment: Give the li elements a class and hide the class. Grouping them with div is not the right solution.

Comment: @Arno I've posted an answer answering your question to hide some list items. The jsfiddle contains an example with buttons as well. Is this what you are looking for? If not, please add more description of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you wish to hide all elements but the first 3**

You can use [:gt](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category-module.souvenir li:gt(2)').css('display','none');
});
```

or you can use [.slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category-module.souvenir li').slice(3).css('display','none');
});
```

**Wish to hide elements between x and y?**

For example hide 3,4 and 5:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.category-module.souvenir li').slice(2,5).css('display', 'none');
});
```

[Jsfiddle with all 3 examples](https://jsfiddle.net/xsoc0emm/21/)